# Animation does not pause when switched between browser tabs

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm new to HTML5 and basically using code structure similar to one found here http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-start-and-stop-an-animation/

According to Paul Irish the animation is paused automatically when switched between tabs when requestAnimationFrame() is used

http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

But in the first example it doesn't pause but continues to move and also sometimes disappears when we switch browser tab.
I found an example where the animation does tend to work perfectly.

http://jsfiddle.net/wMkJg/

How can I modify the code so that the animation does not continue on tab switch?

```
function animate(lastTime, myRectangle, runAnimation, canvas, context) {

                if(runAnimation.value) {
                  // update
                  var time = (new Date()).getTime();
                  var timeDiff = time - lastTime;

                  // pixels / second
                  var linearSpeed = 100;
                  var linearDistEachFrame = linearSpeed * timeDiff / 1000;
                  var currentX = myRectangle.x;

                  if(currentX < canvas.width - myRectangle.width - myRectangle.borderWidth / 2) {
                    var newX = currentX + linearDistEachFrame;
                    myRectangle.x = newX;
                  }

                  // clear
                  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                  // draw
                  drawRect(myRectangle, context);

                  // request new frame
                  requestAnimFrame(function() {
                    animate(time, myRectangle, runAnimation, canvas, context);
                  });


        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of rAF is not defined. In some browsers it *may* pause, in others it *may* reduce the frame rate and so forth, but this is not defined by the standard.

You can use the focus and blur events on the window to set a flag your loop can use:

```
var isPaused = false;

window.onblur = function() {
    isPaused = true;
}
window.onfocus = function() {
    isPaused = false;
    animate(...);     /// start the loop (or use rAF here too)
}
```

And then in your loop:

```
requestAnimFrame(function() {
    if (!isPaused) animate(time, myRectangle, runAnimation, canvas, context);
});
```

Comment: thank you ken, so is this a know problem or is the logic given in the example wrong?